# SQL Server BULK INSERT Fails on Computer-Generated Files. Possible Permission Issue?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

With SQL Server, I have this stored procedure:

```
BULK INSERT cowords_batch_1
FROM 'E:\wikipedia\todb\batch1.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='\t', ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

Here's what the `batch1.txt` file looks like:

```
2   224620  0.5
2   191679  0.2
2   185763  0.5
2   275974  0.33333334
2   263506  0.25
```

And here's the `cowords_batch_1` table the data goes into:

```
[word_id] [int] NULL,
[coword_id] [int] NULL,
[total_proximity] [decimal](18, 9) NULL
```

When the procedure is executed, I expect SQL Server is going to read the text file and insert the rows into the table. What happens is actually dependent on how the original text file being imported was created.

1. If I create the file manually and type data into it, the import is successful.
2. If I create a file programatically, the import fails with

   > Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.upload, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 2]
   > Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 3 (total_proximity).
3. If I copy the data from the file in #2 above and paste it into the file in #1 above, the import is successful.
4. If I copy the data from the file in #1 above and paste it into the file in #2 above, the import fails with the same error.
5. If I manually type data into the file in #2 above, the import fails.

The only thing in common between the failed attempts is that the actual file on the drive was created by my software.

The only thing in common between the successful attempts is that the actual file on the drive was created manually using `Notepad.exe`.

I have stepped through byte-by-byte and confirmed that the files are as expected, including ascii 9 between the fields and ascii 10 at the end of each row.

To me, the behavior seems to point to permissions, but the error message and the properties of the files don't seem to back that up. I gave Everybody full control over the directory and all the files say the owner is Everybody:

[image: batch1.txt properties]

Again, it seems as though the only differentiator between success and failure here is how the original file was created; moving the content between the files does not make a difference, so at this point I am confident the content is not the issue.

What should I look at now?

Comment: Doesn't sound like permissions (or the content), sounds like the machine-generated file is created in a different codepage. Could you try with `... ROWTERMINATOR='\n', CODEPAGE = '65001');`? Or `CODEPAGE = 'ACP'`? If you open a good file and bad file in notepad, then try to save as, does notepad offer you different encoding?

Comment: I don't think you're looking at the same file. Your screen shot says it's 17 bytes long, but the example data you've given is 76 bytes in ASCII/ANSI format (or UTF-8 without a Byte Order mark).

Comment: Good observation AlwaysLearning but it was just a timing thing. I posted the screenshot only to point out what the permissions are on the files in the directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rhythm. I tried the CODEPAGE settings and got the same result. Also, If I do a Save As, both files default to UTF-8.

Comment: Bearing in mind that file system paths are relative to the SQL Server instance's viewpoint... is SQL Server on the same computer as you and looking at the same `E:\wikipedia\todb\batch1.txt` file that you are?

Comment: Yes AlwaysLearning, it is on the same computer. The files are all in the same directory as well. It is unmistakable: if I manually create a file and paste data into it, it will work. If I copy and paste the same data into a file that was previously created by my application (replacing its contents in its entirety) it will fail. It seems always as if there is a file attribute or the way the file is stored that makes the difference.

Comment: Aha! Rhythm your suggestion about CODEPAGE and SaveAs options got me looking down a different path. I noticed at the bottom of Notepad it displays a property. The files that work it says Windows (CRLF) and for the ones that don't work it says Unix (LF). I changed my code that produces the files to use CRLF and my files now work.

Comment: If you need to deal with LF line endings down the road you can change `ROWTERMINATOR='\n'` to `ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a'`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I went back and changed '\n' to '0x0a' then uploaded a file that was not working (one that had only LF as a row terminator) and it worked! I find it hard to believe that this could be an issue with the BULK INSERT, but it certainly looks like '\n' for a row terminator is not being processed correctly. In any event, do what you suggested works. If you rephrase repost it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!